# Problem with generating code in pre-build

Tags: c#, python

For my project i need auto generated code for GRPC. I generate this code using a .bat/.sh file.

But when i generate the code in the pre-build, the code fails because it contains errors.

Then all the errors show op, but they quickly dissapear, because now it is finding the generated code and there are no errors.

I tried running the script with the name of the script as the prebuild command, where the build determines the extension of the script.

I tried running the commands from python too and even add a sleep after the generation has finished, but sadly nothing worked.

The pre-build cript in visual studio:

```
python generate.py
```

The python script:

```py
import sys
import os
import time
print("Working dir: " + os.getcwd())
if("win" in sys.platform):
    os.system('generate.bat')
else:
    os.system("bash \"" + os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/generate.sh' + "\"")
print("done installing")
time.sleep(5)
print("done finalising")
```

The build output:

```
1>done installing
1>done finalising
1>CSharp\TimelineEvents.cs(18,32,18,48): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PayloadOneofCase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>CSharp\FrontendEndpointGrpc.cs(28,31,28,51): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RegisterFileResponse' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>Done building project "Protocol.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

I would expect that the build waits for the pre-build, but that does not seem to be the case, as the build fails when you run the generate for the first time, but when i build it again it runs just fine

Comment: The cause seems to be in the choice of `os.system` over [`os.subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess). I believe `os.system` returns immediately after creating a sub-shell, whereas as `os.subprocess` will run within the current process and so will wait until it is completed before returning.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I will try this, but it also fails when i just exectue generate.bat as the pre-build, so i don't know if that is the problem.

Comment: Ok i just tried this, but sadly it did not work

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem by changing the project file from this:

```
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="python generate.py" />
```

To this:

```
  <Target Name="Generate" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="Generating GRPC code" />
    <Exec Command="python generate.py" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="CSharp\**\*.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

This fixed the problem for me

Comment: Additionally, you can remove it from automatic recognition so you don't get a warning for a double file when it's already there before the build:

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="YourFiles.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>